# Using focus out events and mutation observers in Adobe Dtm

Tags: adobe-analytics

I see that there is only a limited amount of event types we can use in the Adobe  DTM user interface . How can we use the above focus out and mutation observers to Capture user interactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterpart to "focus" is "blur", and it is available as an **Event Type** for **Event Based Rules**.

Mutation observers are not currently available in DTM, so you will need to write your own code for that.  You can put it in a **Page Load Rule** as a **Javascript / Third Party Tag**, and have it trigger a **Direct Call Rule**.